# X-Frame-Options issue?

Tags: visualforce, iframe

My requirement is to show a standard VF page into a Custom Visualforce page. I am using apex:iframe with 'src' parameter and the value as relative url to the standard VF page. However it does not give any error at compile time but at the runtime it only shows a blank page. Then I opened the developer console on the browser, it shows an error. That says "Refused to display 'https://ap2.salesforce.com/001' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'".

This is my iframe.

```
<apex:iframe src="https://ap2.salesforce.com/001" scrolling="true"/>
```

Comment: You can't display a standard page in an iframe. You can "recreate" the functionality of a standard page using visualforce commands if that's what you want to do. You can also call the standard page using a recordId if you want a detail page (looks like you're trying get an account page). Salesforce generally discourages the use of iframes for security reasons.

Comment: for more detail on this issue see this:[http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121164/salesforce-summer-16-page-not-loading-in-iframe/121168#121168](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121164/salesforce-summer-16-page-not-loading-in-iframe/121168#121168)

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and the solution was to uncheck

"Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled"

in Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings

[image: Session Settings]

Comment: Hello, I am having the same error. I tried to uncheck the Clickjack protection settings. But it still gives the same error. I also added a similar question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249474/refused-to-display-https-www-salesforce-com-de-in-a-frame-because-it-set-x

could you please have a look and suggest something ? :)

Comment: doesn't work for me either both of the options are unchecked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my case, with a url from Google, adding `'&output=embed'` to the url made the trick

Answer (score -2):

I've experienced this issue before and found that having the Salesforce Developer Mode on was causing the issue.

This can be turned off by navigating to Setup -> Users -> Your User -> Turn Developer Mode off

Answer (score -2):

keep showHeader = false in apex:page