# 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a Visualforce with embeded page from the Moodle site but in the Production I got this error in console log

> Refused to display 'https://learn.psa.org.au/enrol/index.php?id=2848'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

but in the sandbox its works fine

Comment: Please have a look at this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/207627/20721)

Answer (score 2):

Actually **Clickjack protection secures your Visualforce pages against user interface redress attacks**.

Salesforce provide 2 ways to apply this protection:

1. By enabling a global setting
2. Keeping salesforce default header in your page that is `ShowHeader=true`

So Clickjack protection is implemented by salesforce by adding a X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN header to Visualforce pages. When headers are suppressed by setting showHeader="false" on a page, this header isn’t added to the page, and clickjack protection is disabled.

**But** what if you want this protection to be enabled also you don't want to show header as well, for this salesforce has provided global setting:

*Enable clickjack protection for customer Visualforce pages with headers disabled*

under **Setup | Security Controls | Session Settings**

Enabling clickjack protection for Visualforce pages has some side effects. When this header is activated, only pages served from the Visualforce domain can wrap Visualforce pages in an , or otherwise embed Visualforce pages.

You have two options for handling existing framed Visualforce pages.

1. Discontinue displaying these pages within a frame or . **This
   solution is recommended.**
2. Don’t enable clickjack protection for your Visualforce pages. This
   option allows you to continue framing Visualforce pages, but the
   pages are vulnerable to clickjack attacks. **This option isn’t
   recommended.**