# Refused to display 'https://www.salesforce.com/de/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: visualforce, security, iframe, x-frame-options

I created VF page    (or also to see the VF page inside a lightning component).
I added an apex iframe with src="https://www.salesforce.com/de/" (or any other source) from [salesforce apex iframe guide.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_iframe.htm)

```
<apex:iframe src="http://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
```

I also did Uncheck the Clickjack protection from this [SO question-answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121260/x-frame-options-issue) and some other posts and also added the website url to the Whitelisted Domains for VF inline frames.

Setup > Security Controls > Session Settings

I also added the website url to the CSP trusted sites.

[image]

However, I am still getting the error :-

**Refused to display 'https://www.salesforce.com/de/?ir=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.**

Could someone please suggest a Solution OR any ideas?

My VF page looks like :-

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0"  sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en" style="height: 100%;">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Iframe page</title>

        <style type="text/css" >
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <apex:iframe src="http://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Or just a normal VF page

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false">
<body>
    <apex:iframe src="http://www.salesforce.com" scrolling="true" id="theIframe"/>        
</body>
```

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this? i am facing the same issue, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem so I did contact the salesforce and the resolution suggested by Salesforce is to add the following tags to the apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0"

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" >
```

Comment: getting same error, but adding the attributes as given does not solves the problem. Did you get any solution to this or by doing this, did it solved your issue?

Comment: Yes. It solved my problem.