# set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'. Error When Launching a Visual Flow from VF

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, lightning-experience, visual-workflow

I have created custom button and on button I am calling a VF page where I have specified the Visual flow by using  parameter.Whenever I launch the flow,it display the blank screen and in console tab,it display below error message:
[image]

I am not sure what needs to be done here.Logic in my visual flow is proper but not sure what needs to be done?

Can someone give me some hint how to get rid of this error?

Comment: did you check http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/121164/salesforce-summer-16-page-not-loading-in-iframe/121168#121168

Comment: Yes i have already referred the link but it still does not work in my case